# how is assignment by reference done in Qt for QObjects?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In Qt, when trying to assign a reference I am getting `use of deleted function` error:

```
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/users.cpp:16: error: use of deleted function 'User::User(const User&)'
     User user=users_map.value("email@domain.com");
                                                 ^
         ^
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/users.h:7: In file included from ../QML1/users.h:7:0,
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/users.cpp:1: from ../QML1/users.cpp:1:
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/user.h:6: 'User::User(const User&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class User : public QObject
       ^
/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QObject:1: In file included from /opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QObject:1:0,
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/users.h:4: from ../QML1/users.h:4,
/home/niko/QT_snippets/QML1/users.cpp:1: from ../QML1/users.cpp:1:
```

In C, I was always using pointers and I never had any problem, but as I see in C++ everybody uses references.

How should I assign an object by reference in Qt? For example, in this line how should I make the `user` object be a reference to a value in `users_map` object?

```
User user=users_map.value("email@domain.com");
```

Or maybe the following?

```
User user=&users_map.value("email@domain.com");
```

Because... the code above does not compile. I need to use it inside methods of `Users` class to access the data in `users_map` variable.

The `Users` class is declared as:

```
class Users : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    enum UserRoles {
        EmailRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        NameRole,
        PasswordRole
    };
private:
    QMap<QString,User>         users_map;
public:
    explicit Users(QAbstractItemModel *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QModelIndex index(int row, int column,const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
signals:

public slots:
};
```

The `User` class is declared like this:

```
class User : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString email READ get_email WRITE set_email NOTIFY emailChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ get_name WRITE set_name NOTIFY nameChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ get_password WRITE set_password NOTIFY passwordChanged);
private:
    QString             email;
    QString             name;
    QString             password;
public:
    explicit User(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString get_email();
    void set_email(QString data);
    QString get_name();
    void set_name(QString data);
    QString get_password();
    void set_password(QString data);

signals:
    void emailChanged();
    void nameChanged();
    void passwordChanged();

public slots:
};
```

Comment: `User& user=users_map.value("email@domain.com");`

Comment: *"when trying to assign a reference"* -- You never tried assigning a reference. And you do it with QT objects the same way you do it with any other object. I'd suggest a beginner's book in C++ before trying to use an advanced library like QT.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik there is no implementation of `QMap::value` returning a reference, so your code is still wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as I see in C++ everybody uses references.

You shouldn't trust what you see :)

---

`QObject` has a deleted copy constructor, so de facto your derived class `User` has a deleted copy constructor as well and can't be copied. That's the meaning of this error:

```
use of deleted function 'User::User(const User&)'
```

In the following line:

```
User user=&users_map.value("email@domain.com");
```

The `&` takes the address of `users_map.value("email@domain.com")`, so you're basically creating a (dangling) pointer of type `User*` to element returned by copy by `QMap::value`.

You may change your code like this to get a reference:

```
User& user=users_map["email@domain.com"];
```

Note that there is no [`QMap::value`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#value) implementation returning a reference, so you must here use [`QMap::operator[]`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) (you may want to check if `"email@domain.com"` is indeed a key contained in the map; it will be silently added otherwise).

However be aware that `QObject` (and derived classes) is designed to be used with pointers, so your declaration:

```
QMap<QString, User> users_map;
```

Looks like a bad design in a Qt perspective, and you may encounter more errors of this type.

---

BTW the correct spelling is Qt, not QT which stands for QuickTime ;)

Comment: Thanks for very useful comments! It does compile this line of code when I add '&', however later it throws another compilation error saying that the instantiation of 'const T QMap<K, V>' required from 'const T QMap<K, V>::operator[] causes an error of type `error: use of deleted function 'User::User(const User&)'` . But anyway, I will change everything to pointers to QObjects. I thought that for passing objects from C++ to QML I need to do it by reference and not by pointer. So , if you say pointers are better I just switch to pointers and forget about references. Thanks again!